# How can I save a file in PHP to a directory higher than current?

Tags: php

The script is in myusername/public_html/item/index.php

code to save file:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../data/guestbook.txt';
        $filehandle = fopen($filename, 'ab+') or die("<p>Unable to create the file!</p>\n".$filename);
        flock($filehandle, LOCK_EX) or die("<p>Unable to lock the file!</p>\n");
        fwrite($filehandle, $new_entry) or die("<p>Unable to write to the file!</p>\n");
        fclose($filehandle);
```

For some reason it fails on the fopen and the filename is actually ends up being literally with the /../ instead of navigating to the proper path.

What to do, what to do?

Comment: Did you check directory/file permissions to make sure you have access? I remember writing code that can almost write to any arbitrary location.

Comment: @ashes999 Yes, I have access to the data directory :/

Comment: What's the output of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I navigate to a higher directory to save a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848674/how-can-i-navigate-to-a-higher-directory-to-save-a-file)

Comment: Why do people have an obsession with "duplicate" questions on here. Who cares? haha

Comment: @antonpug: because dupe questions are like little kids asking "are we there yet?" 500 times a minute.

Comment: @antonpug: because SO isn't a forum. In any case, we need to keep the [noise](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/signal-to-noise-ratio.html) down, otherwise it becomes harder & harder for people to find an appropriate Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code like this if the php script is in the item folder and item and data are at the same level in the directory hierarchy

```
$savedir = '../data/';
$filename = $savedir.'guestbook.txt';
```

make sure apache user has the write access to the directory by "chown -R apache:apache" and "chmod 755".

Probably the " /../ " in your code is giving the error. Try removing the first forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason it fails on the fopen

There is no "some reasons" in programming. There are always a certain reason.
And you have to know it.

> filename is actually ends up being literally with the /../

That's exactly what you wrote, nothing to complain of.

> How can I save a file in PHP to a directory higher than current?

Technically you are setting it correct.

**But there can be another reason, other than wrong way of the path creation.**
Yes, there always can be **many** reasons for the program to fail!

> What to do, what to do?

Run this code and see what it says.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../data/guestbook.txt';
file_put_contents($filename,$new_entry);
```

it will tell you the reason why it fails.